# Docker: Cannot connect to database after pull private image from self-hosted registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs, gitlab-ci

I have a project written in nest.js as nodejs framework and using typeorm(postgres) as database. I ran it using `docker compose up` and there is no problem in run and send request to it. I deploy it to a self-hosted registry using `gitlab-ci` but after pulling the created image from `gitlab-ci` and run the image, the nest.js app cannot connect to database with the following error:

```
[Nest] 1  - 12/16/2022, 7:32:15 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26)
```

this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim
EXPOSE 3000
RUN mkdir /app && chown -R node:node /app
WORKDIR /app
USER node
ARG NPM_TOKEN
COPY .npmrc .npmrc
COPY package*.json yarn*.lock ./
COPY --chown=node:node . .
RUN yarn && yarn build && yarn cache clean
RUN rm -f .npmrc
CMD ["node", "./dist/main.js"]
```

and my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
      args:
        NPM_TOKEN: $NPM_TOKEN
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: $DB_USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $DB_PASS
      POSTGRES_DB: $DB_NAME
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${DB_NAME}", "-U", "${DB_USER}" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
```

`.env`:

```
SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
SERVER_PORT=3000

# Database
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=password
DB_NAME=discussion
DB_SYNC=true
DB_AUTOLOAD=true

DEVELOPMENT=true
NPM_TOKEN=
```

and finally my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
    pull_policy: always
  variables:
    VERSION: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"auth\":\"$(echo -n ${CI_REGISTRY_USER}:${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} | base64 -w 0)\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - cp .env.default .env
    - echo $NPM_TOKEN >> .env
    - ls -a
    - touch deploy.env
    - >-
      /kaniko/executor 
      --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR 
      --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile 
      --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION
      --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=$NPM_TOKEN
    - |
      cat << EOF  > deploy.env
      IMAGE_REF=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION
      EOF
  after_script:
    - cat deploy.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: deploy.env
```

Note that I have no problem in running using `docker compose up` in my local machine